# Including Multiple File Paths in Open API Doc

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have quite a large API with many wheels turning. Documenting all of these in one giant `openapi.yaml` file isn't easy for me so I decided to breakdown the docs to separate `paths` as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now in my `customer.yaml` file I have the following routes:

```
/customers/new:
/customers/login:
/customers/logout:
```

And in my `partner.yaml` file I have the following routes:

```
/partners/new:
/partners/login:
/partners/logout:
```

Now I included the above two files into my final `index.yaml` file as below

```
paths:
  - $ref: "./paths/partner.yaml"
  - $ref: "./paths/customer.yaml"
```

But the final generated doc by the `swagger-cli` is adding the `-` character before the path references thereby resulting in a malformed unusable document.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you show an example on the structure of the customer.yaml?

I get a lot of errors like

requestBody is not expected here when i include path files...

Answer (score 1):

`paths` in OpenAPI is a map, not an array, so you can't use the yaml `-`  syntax.

You need to include the pathItem keys in your top level file, and put the `$ref`s to the relevant file or fragment of a file there.

For example:

```yaml
paths:
  /foo:
    $ref: "./foo.yaml"
  /bar:
    $ref: "./paths.yaml#/paths/bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But is that a realistic way of doing things? That would mean that I need to have different files for all different operations for a particular path. That is to say `createNewPartner` would be in a file different from `updatePartner`??

Comment: There's no reason you can't have more than one pathItem in the file you reference and use things like `$ref: './paths.yaml#/paths/foo'`, as in my second example.

Comment: Could you show how you think the contents of the foo.yaml and the paths.yaml should be organized for this to work?